# pandasで、うまく、最大の行数を変更できません。

Tags: python, pandas

pandasで、うまく、最大の行数を変更できません。

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 50)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
df_list[0]
```

どうすれば、最大の行数を変更することが出来るのでしょうか？
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 「最大の行数を変更」とは具体的にはどういうことでしょうか？ oririさんの回答のように先頭500行を表示させたい、などの意味でしょうか？？

Comment: `max_rows < DataFrame`, で, そのままでは全件表示は無理なので, `head`, `tail` などの利用を回答に記しましたが, 想定している表示形式・表示する内容・データの取捨選択があるのなら, 質問に書き加えたほうがよいかも

Comment: [pd.describe_option('display')](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.describe_option.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display.max_rows, 500` ですが, 件数が多いようなので

先頭だけなら

```py
df.head(500)
```

最後の方なら

```py
df.tail(500)
```

適当なら

```py
df.sample(500)
```

…を試してみてください
全件ならばこういうのも

```py
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

# あるいは少し意味違うけど
# df.style
```

---

##### 追記

どのような表示か, 質問になかったので推測ですが,
途中省略された形式のまま少し件数を増やしたいとかでしょうか？
`min_rows`, `max_rows` と実際の行数との兼ね合いになるけど以下で可能

```py
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 500)
pd.set_option("display.min_rows", 500)

display(df)
```

参考:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#frequently-used-options

Comment: 返事が遅くなり申し訳ありません。私が考えていたことは、難しいそうなので、`head(), tail()`などで表示したいと思います。ありがとうございました。